# how to connect browsed file

Tags: java, file, jsp, file-upload, odbc

I am new to programming. I am trying to upload excel file and its contents to MSSQL database. By using this code I can get file browser window. after submission it should perform according to upload.jsp.

```
     <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
```

upload.jsp is using for take the browsed file name and then upload its contents into a database using appropriate query.

using ODBC I can connect Excel database. but here I need to mention Book1.xls. but I can't take the browsed file name from the above code.

```
 Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" ); 
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel 
 Driver(*.xls)};DBQ=**book1.xls**; readOnly= false");
```

I am using this code to access the browsed file name

```
   String contentType = request.getContentType();
   out.println("<title>JSP File upload</title>");
   DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        // Create a new file upload handler
   ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            // Parse the request to get file items.
    List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            // Process the uploaded file items
    Iterator m = fileItems.iterator();
    FileItem fi = (FileItem)m.next();
    String fileName1=fi.getName();
    out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName1 + "<br>");
```

How can I connect browsed file name with ODBC. that means

```
   Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" ); 
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel 
   Driver(*.xls)};DBQ=**fileName1**; readOnly= false");
```

instead of book1.xls how to call browsed filename fileName1?

Comment: The connection string is just a string. Looks like you know how to concatenate them (you do that already in `println`). What exactly is your problem?

Comment: i need to connect that +fileName1+ in DBQ=**book1.xls**;

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, this should do it:

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver(*.xls)};DBQ=**" + fileName1 + "**; readOnly= false");`

**Edit:**
From your comments, I realized that the ODBC driver is looking for a file on the disk, but you haven't written it to the disk in your example. The DiskFileItemFactory *might* write it to a temporary file somewhere, but there's no guarantee of that, and it's certainly not at "fileName1".

So you need to write the file out somewhere first. Probably something like the following code. This *may* work as written, but there might be trouble with the path... I'm not sure if `fi.getName()` returns a full path or just a name. Either way, you should probably set up a folder somewhere for these files, and specify the full path to it.

```
File outFile = new File(fileName1);
fi.write(outFile);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver(*.xls)};DBQ=**" + fileName1 + "**; readOnly= false");
```

Comment: :-yes you are rite.. but that is not working. instead am gettin this error                         java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Read more: http://localhost:8080/trythis/up.jsp

Comment: Ah, sorry! I see the problem now. I edited my answer. Let us know if that helps.